# SELECT query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
ID | DATE
1  |  16-01-2012
2  |  17-01-2012
3  |  18-01-2012
4  |  22-01-2012
5  |  28-01-2012
6  |  02-02-2012
```

My task is:

I have a `date` variable which is initialised to `16-01-2012` and I have to find all rows  which are in continuum with `16-01-2012`  i.e `17-01-2012` and `18-01-2012`.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a [hierarchical query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) like the following:

```
with data (id, date)
as
(
    select id, date from yourtable where date = '16-01-2012'
    UNION ALL
    select t.id, t.date
    from yourtable t
    inner join data d 
      on  DATEDIFF(dd, d.date, t.date) = 1
    -- 1 day difference
)
select
    *
from
    data
;
```

I don't have an SQL server here to try this out, so there might be some errors in the statement. It should give you an idea though.

Comment: on  DATEDIFF(dd, t.Date, d.Date) = -1

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Thanks. Isn't simple subtraction working in SQL server?

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Why exactly? Doesn't SQL server support subtraction of dates that way?

Comment: "Operand data type date is invalid for subtract operator." I suppose they can't decide what the difference means, is it about days, months, years etc.

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Thanks - I assumed it worked the same way as in Oracle. There it is a decimal representing the difference in days.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth tried your sample and it works fine. Thanks +1

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select id, date 
from table 
where date > date_from_variable
```

The only think you have jet to do, is to cast your variable to the right date format.

sample:

```
cast(date_from_variable, smalldate)
```

Comment: -1: This returns all elements that are bigger than the specified variable, no matter whether or not there is a gap in between.